# Unit test is only running one test (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I am trying to implement some unit-testing, and I have various different input files I want to call into my program to test. The function I want to test is located in `my_file`,
for a function called `test_func`.

Here is my code:

```py
import unittest
import make_html
    
  
class TestBuild(unittest.TestCase):
        def test_test_func(self):
            # Case 1: blank input file -> Return 'Blank'
            expected_output = 'Blank'
            self.assertEqual(make_html.test_func('blank'),expected_output)

            # Case 2: Non-numeric -> Should raise ValueError
            with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
                make_html.test_func('non_numeric')
                                  

if __name__ == '__main__': # run the main file within unit test package
    unittest.main()
```

When I try to run this unit test, it only ever runs 1 of the tests. If I run them separately, they return 'OK'. What am I doing wrong? How do I get it so both tests are run. Furthermore, I want to add even more cases. I am not really sure what it going in here, regarding the syntax surrounding `class`, `self`, `__name__` and `__main__`.

Update: I tried splitting it into two tests, but I am getting the same result:

```py
import unittest
import make_html
    
  
class TestBuild(unittest.TestCase):
        def test_test_func(self):
            # Case 1: blank input file -> Return 'Blank'
            expected_output = 'Blank'
            self.assertEqual(make_html.test_func('blank'),expected_output)

        def test_test_func(self):
            # Case 2: Non-numeric -> Should raise ValueError
            with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
                make_html.test_func('non_numeric')
                                  

if __name__ == '__main__': # run the main file within unit test package
    unittest.main()
```

My output is still just:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s
```

Comment: While what you wrote is legal, you'll get better reporting if you break your test into two separate tests. How do you know only one test runs, and what does `test_func` actually do?

Comment: Can you include the code of your second test as well?

Comment: When you say "tests", do you mean the `assert`s? Because technically you only have 1 test: `test_test_func`. And please also [edit] to show the actual output that you get on the console/terminal when you run this. If the 1st `assert` fails, then the rest of the `assert`ions in that test are skipped.

Comment: @GinoMempin Oh, I see now. I thought each of the asserts were multiple tests. How would I split this into two separate tests?

Comment: @quamrana sorry - I have made a mistake. Case 2 should be the second test. I thought this was how it was supposed to be written.

Comment: By splitting it into multiple `def test_xxxx` functions? There are some examples in the unittest docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#basic-example

Comment: In your updated version of the test you have used the same method name. The second overwrites the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need another test method:

```py
class TestBuild(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_blank(self):
        # Case 1: blank input file -> Return 'Blank'
        expected_output = 'Blank'
        self.assertEqual(make_html.test_func('blank'),expected_output)
    def test_ValueError(self):
        # Case 2: Non-numeric -> Should raise ValueError
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            make_html.test_func('non_numeric')
```

Comment: Okay, I see what I did wrong. I was using the same function names... Thanks for that!